# Writing a removeLast method

Tags: c#, arrays

**Situation:**

I'm new to c# and currently learning the ropes whilst also polishing up on my data structures, I decided to make a class that'd perform multiple functions to a linear array, since It was suggested to me that I should start with linear arrays then work on a circular one.

The methods my class currently provides are:

- adding an item to the front-most position of the array,
- adding an item to the back-most position of the array,
- removing the first item in the array,
- removing the last item in the array, ***//todo***
- clearing the current array list of it's values,
- displaying the array list contents to the user.

**Problem:**

I'm having difficulty constructing a method that removes the last item of the array, I've looked online and the pre-writen methods seem complex and I can't get my head around them due to my in-experience. I realize it must be easy for others to write a method like this, but I'm truly stumped.

I'd like to learn how to write a method that removes the last value in the array, in the most simpliest to understand way. Here is my current code for my LinearArrayList class.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace arraydatastructuresactual
{
    public class LinearArrayList
    {
        private int count;  //how many numbers currently stored
        private int[] values;  //array to hold values entered into list

        //constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// //creates a linear array that can hold max values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="max"></param>
        public LinearArrayList(int max)
        {
            count = 0;

            values = new int[max]; //makes the linear array as big as the max value
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// //default constructor sets capacity to 10
        /// </summary>
        public LinearArrayList()
        {
            count = 0;

            values = new int[10];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// returns true if list is empty
        /// otherwise turns false
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true if empty otherwise false</returns>
        public bool isEmpty()
        {
            return (count == 0);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// returns true if list is full
        /// otherwise turns false
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true if full otherwise false</returns>
        public bool isFull()
        {
            return (values.Length <= count);

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// if not full adds value to the end of list
        /// throws exception if list is fulll
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">value to add to end of list</param>
        public void addLast(int value) //adds an item to the last position in the array.
        {
            if (isFull())
            {
                throw new Exception("List Full");
            }
            else
            {
                values[count++] = value;
            }
        }

        public void addFirst(int value) //Adds an item to the first position in the array.
        {
            if (isFull())
            {
                throw new Exception("List Full");
            }
            else
            {

                for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    values[i] = values[i--];
                }
                values[0] = value;
                count++;

            }
        }

        public int removeFirst() //removes the first item from the array
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new Exception("List is Empty");

            int value = values[0];
            count--;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                values[i] = values[i + 1];
            }

            return value;
        }

        public int removeLast() //todo //removes the last item from the array
        {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new Exception("List is Empty");

            int value = values[0];
            count--;
            for (int i = count; i < count; i++)
            {
                values[i] = values[i + 1];
            }

            return value;
        }


        public void displayUI()//displays contents of list
        {

        }
        public void destroy() //Empties The List
        {

        }

    }
}
```

If someone could share their experience on how I'd go about achieving this, then many thanks, I tried to repurpose my removeFirst method but I messed up, tried to do this a few times and I'm completely stumped now.

Comment: Last = value[count] then decrement count?

Comment: You understand there is already an Array class...right?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm learning about c# and the IDE mostly (and Data Structures), I wrote this program/class to better understand stacks/data management

Like I said, I'd use prewritten code in libraries but I find it complex and optimized, I'm trying to go over the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write

```
public int removeLast() 
{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("List is Empty");

    count--;
    return values[count];
}
```

this will return the last item in the values array WITHOUT changing its size but decrementing the variable that keeps track of the item actually inserted in the array.
Notice that I don't try to change the value in the  location pointed by the count variable. It is still there until you overwrite it adding another value

So you could still write this

```
// Creates an array with space for 10 ints 
LinearArrayList la = new LinearArrayList();
la.addLast(34);   
la.addLast(23);   
la.addLast(56);   
la.addLast(467);
la.addLast(43);
la.addLast(666);
la.addLast(7989);
la.addLast(82);
la.addLast(569);
la.addLast(100);  
int value = la.removeLast();

// This will work because you still have a slot free in the 10 ints array 
la.addLast(1110);

// While this will fail because the array has now all slots filled
la.addLast(9435);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Sybren's answer:

```
int lastValue = values[values.Length - 1];
int[] newValues = new int[values.Length - 1];
Array.Copy(values, newValues, newValues.Length);
values = newValues;
return lastValue;
```

---

or

```
int lastValue = values[values.Length - 1];
Array.Resize(values, values.Length - 1);
return lastValue;
```

---

If you don't want to use any existing methods of `Array` class, you can also:

```
int lastValue = values[values.Length - 1];
int[] newValues = new int[values.Length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < newValues.Length; i++)
{
    newValues[i] = values[i];
}
values = newValues;
return lastValue;
```

### Edit

Forget this, do what @Steve said.

Comment: Thanks, The last answer was kinda what I was looking for, I didn't really want to use the existing Array method.

Comment: This makes a different array with a smaller size. This means that the initial constructor size is no more valid so it cannot store a new value in the previous last position. To be complete then you need an add method that resizes the array if larger than current length. In other words you need to reimplement a List

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it. You're converting your array to a list, getting the last element from the list, removing the last element from the list, and convert it back to an array.

```
    var numbersList = values.ToList();
    var last = numbersList.Last();
    numbersList.Remove(last);
    values = numbersList.ToArray();
    return last;
```